# google-apps-script getValue last character

Tags: string, google-apps-script, character

I am a begineer in script programming and I want to get the last character of cells in order to compare to another character. I do not know the function to do this.

Example: cells value is "250815H", I want to get "H" only.

Hereafter my script:

```
//Déclaration des variables
var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Sheet of forms response
var LastRow= SheetResponse .getLastRow(); //last row of sheet (n)
var LastCell = SheetResponse.getRange(LastRow,2).getValue(); //get last cell value in column B
var LastChar = LastCell.getStringRight(1); //get last character from right
```

Thank you in davance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such situations, you can employ most of the basic Javascript goodies, so in case of problems, you can google it: here you'd have to search for *javascript last character of a string* or similar.

Thus, in this case, you could use:

```
var LastChar = LastCell.slice(-1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. The script is functional.